# MPEG-DASH MPEG2-TS support in Chromecast and other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, google-cast, mpeg, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-dash

Could someone provide a definitive answer to the current state of support of MPEG2-TS under MPEG-DASH with various browsers especially Chromecast?

There are proofs that Chromecast can do mp4 and webm via MPEG-DASH. But I do not see any clear confirmation  of support or non-support on MPEG2-TS.

My guess is that base on the non-support of MPEG2-TS in Google's MSE, Chromecast is not likely to support MPEG2-TS with MPEG-DASH. But I would like a firm confirmation.

Any other mainstream browsers that may support MPEG DASH/MPEG2-TS?

Thanks

Comment: The ChromeCast website (https://developers.google.com/cast/supported_media_types) clearly indicates that MPEG2-TS is not supported.  Also, support in Chrome is listed here (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video).  I do not believe that any major browsers intend on supporting MPEG2-TS and MSE.  Chrome and IE 11 are the only browsers, I believe, to currently offer MSE support and neither supports MPEG2-TS.  I imagine if Apple puts MSE support into Safari it would support MPEG2-TS, but I don't think that's coming any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As my message indicated that I am aware the Chromecast MSE currently does not support MPEG2-TS. My question was on  Chromecase MPEG-DASH MPEG2-TS support. Closely related questions but not identical.

Comment: I specifically linked to the media that Chromecast supports.  Also, Chromecast *is* Chrome, so it's unlikely that MPEG2-TS will be supported on Chromecast if it is not supported on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Media Player Libraries](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player) and the new [Chromecast SDK's](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/release-notes).  MPEG2-TS is supported in Chromecast.

Comment: The links seem to be only accessible to Google employees. Is there a public version of the referenced documentation?

Comment: Thanks! Does this mean that Chrome supports MPEG-TS as well?

Comment: AFAIK - No, Chrome doesn't support MPEG-TS.